# I have two Collections. How do I create a new Collection that extracts the difference between the existing two Collections?

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry for the wordy title! I have a master collection, let's call it List1, and a secondary collection, let's call it List2. I would like to create List3, which consists of the differences between List1 and List2. I defined my variables as Collections because List2 is dynamic and changes in length (code not shown).

```
Dim List1 As New Collection
Dim List2 As New Collection

With List1
    .Add "Soap"
    .Add "Toothbrush"
    .Add "Toothpaste"
    .Add "Showercap"
    .Add "Shampoo"
End With

With List2
    .Add "Toothbrush"
    .Add "Toothapste"
    .Add "Shampoo"
End With
```

Ideally List3 should be a New Collection that consists only of "Soap" and "Showercap".

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You'd use a nested loop to compare the two collections.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I tried during a nested For Each loop (outside loop for List 1, inside loop for List 2), and an innermost if loop to see if one variant from List 1 matches one variant from List 2. The problem is that it only does a variant by variant comparison, when in reality I need it to compare all 3 variants from List2 with a variant from List1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would:

1) create a function to see if the item exists
2) then check each collection by looping through it
3) add to a 3rd collection if it isn't found

example

```
Sub test()

Dim List1 As New Collection
Dim List2 As New Collection
Dim List3 As New Collection

With List1
    .Add "Soap"
    .Add "Toothbrush"
    .Add "Toothpaste"
    .Add "Showercap"
    .Add "Shampoo"
End With

With List2
    .Add "Toothbrush"
    .Add "Toothpaste"
    .Add "Shampoo"
End With

For Each Item In List1
    If Not Exists(List2, Item) Then
        List3.Add (Item)
    End If
Next

For Each Item In List2
    If Not Exists(List1, Item) Then
        List3.Add (Item)
    End If
Next

End Sub


Public Function Exists(col As Collection, key As Variant) As Boolean
    Exists = False

    For Each elm In col
        If key = elm Then
            Exists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. Only error is that you forget to Dim elm As Variant in your function.

Comment: Glad it worked, I didn't have to dim elm in my version for some reason. Please accept as answer if you are using it :)

Answer (score 2):

This is better suited for a Scripting.Dictionary than a `Collection`, because a `Collection` doesn't have an `.Exists` function:

```
Dim list1 As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim list2 As New Scripting.Dictionary

With list1
    .Add "Soap", vbNull
    .Add "Toothbrush", vbNull
    .Add "Toothpaste", vbNull
    .Add "Showercap", vbNull
    .Add "Shampoo", vbNull
End With

With list2
    .Add "Toothbrush", vbNull
    .Add "Toothpaste", vbNull
    .Add "Shampoo", vbNull
End With

Dim differences As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim key As Variant
For Each key In list1.Keys
    If Not list2.Exists(key) Then differences.Add key, vbNull
Next

For Each key In list2.Keys
    If Not list1.Exists(key) Then differences.Add key, vbNull
Next

For Each key In differences
    Debug.Print key
Next
```

Note - this requires a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".  You can add one with Tools->References... from the menu, then find it and check the box next to it.

Comment: I'll give it a go, but other people will be the end users. I'm not sure if they have the aptitude/security clearance to understand or install references.

Comment: @Plaxerous - The reference is stored in the Excel file, and the .dll should be on any reasonably modern (i.e. post around 2000) Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (as per you example) that collection elements are `String`s, I propose you the following "out of the box" approach:

**edited** to account for possible substrings and fix a typo

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim List1 As New Collection
    Dim List2 As New Collection
    Dim List3 As Collection

    With List1
        .Add "Soap"
        .Add "Toothbrush"
        .Add "Toothpaste"
        .Add "Showercap"
        .Add "Shampoo"
    End With

    With List2
        .Add "Toothbrush"
        .Add "Toothpaste"
        .Add "Shampoo"
    End With

    Set List3 = GetDifferenceList(List1, List2)

End Sub


Function GetDifferenceList(List1 As Collection, List2 As Collection) As Collection
    Dim list1Strng As String
    Dim c As New Collection
    Dim elem As Variant

    list1Strng = GetListString(List1)
    For Each elem In List2
        list1Strng = Replace(list1Strng, "|" & CStr(elem) & "|", "|")
    Next elem
    list1Strng = Replace(list1Strng, "||", "|")
    list1Strng = Mid(list1Strng, 2, Len(list1Strng) - 2)

    For Each elem In Split(list1Strng, "|")
      c.Add elem
    Next elem

    Set GetDifferenceList = c
End Function


Function GetListString(List As Collection) As String
    Dim elem As Variant

    For Each elem In List
        GetListString = GetListString & CStr(elem) & "|"
    Next elem
    GetListString = "|" & GetListString
    GetListString = Replace(GetListString, "||", "|")
End Function
```

Comment: You're missing a `"` after `||`.  ;-)

Comment: What happens if there is another list element with the value "Tooth"?

Comment: I'd also add a test for `If elem <> vbNullString` when you build the return `Collection` - it will end up with empty elements without it.

Comment: @Comintern: fixed typo, thank you. While empty strings are dealt with by means of the elimination of "||" string

Comment: @jtolle, edited to handle possible substrings. thanks for the catch